# Using ruby and sinatra how can I schedule a script to run (at an unpredictable time) in the future?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

I am designing a reminder type app. Somebody enters into a form, for example, "call me at such and such a time on such and such a day in the future to remind me of something".

This is put into a postgres database. Obviously lots of people (hopefully) will be doing this and scheduling different things at different times in the future.

So, my question is how can ensure that my app checks the database for things it has to do at the right time? Can I:

a) should I, when the entry is made, create an automated script to execute at the time necessary to perform the reminder function? If so, how?

b) get my app to check the database every minute, again if so how? This would seem a huge waste of resources.

Sorry I cannot provide any code for this but I have no idea where to begin. all help gratefully received.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna use a background job framework like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/). Sidekiq supports [scheduled jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs) like this:

```
Notifier.perform_at(a_time_object, message_to_send)
```

It seems like Sidekiq also [works with Sinatra](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/sinkiq.rb).

Comment: thanks, I have had a preliminary look. It seems to be for rails, will it also work with sinatra?

Comment: @user1903663 : I completely changed my answer from DelayedJob to Sidekiq. That's an other tool that should fullfill our needs.

Answer (score 0):

For that particular task I prefer whenever https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Whenever helps to define Cron tasks. This does not really help to run one-time tasks that should run at different times.